# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un checkbox y después validarlo?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de 3 checkbox y cada uno validarlo por que cada uno va a entrar a una condicion diferente y va hacer algo distinto

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="valor1" id="valor1" class="">valor1
<input type="checkbox" value="valo2" id="valor2" class="">valor2
<input type="checkbox" value="ambos" id="ambos" class="valor">Ambos
```

```js
formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    const valor1 = document.querySelector("#valor1");
    const valor2 = document.querySelector("#valor2");
    const ambos = document.querySelector("#ambos");
    if (valor1.value == "valor1") {
        console.log(estatal)

     //hace algo distinto

    } else if (valor2.value == "valor2") {

        console.log(federal)
    //hace algo distinto

    } else if (ambos.value == "ambos") {
        console.log(ambos)
    }
}
```

Lo que me arroja es que solo entra ala condición 1 si le quito el == "valor1" y si lo dejo como esta en el código no entra a nada no hace ninguna comparación.

Comment: Los 3 elementos son `checkbox`, significa que por ejemplo los 3 pueden estar `checked` al mismo tiempo, pero no veo que este caso lo estes considerando. ¿Estas seguro de que no necesitas usar `radio`s?

Comment: se me ocurrio un checkbox pero si debo de usar radio no hay problema

Comment: Lo que me interesa es que entren ala condicion y en base a lo que selecciono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como ya te ha indicado @Marcos-MD, los checked son booleanos. Y tal como también te ha indicado @Marcos, quizás deberias usar botones de radio (que se autoexcluyen entre sí).

He recopilado ambos casos en este ejemplo funcional para que tu mismo decidas que necesitas hacer realmente, pues tampoco me queda claro cual de ambas opciones te conviene más:

```js
formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const valor1 = document.querySelector("#valor1");
  const valor2 = document.querySelector("#valor2");
  const ambos = document.querySelector("#ambos");
  if (valor1.checked == true) {
    console.log(valor1.value)
  }
  if (valor2.checked == true) {
    console.log(valor2.value)
  }
  if (ambos.checked == true) {
    console.log(ambos.value)
  }
})

formularioRadio.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  seleccionado = document.querySelector('input[name="identico"]:checked').value;
  switch(seleccionado) {
    case 'valor1':
        console.log("valor1")
      break;
    case 'valo2':
        console.log("valo2")
      break;
    case 'ambos':
        console.log("ambos")
      break;
    default:
        break;
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="checkbox" value="valor1" id="valor1">valor1
  <input type="checkbox" value="valo2" id="valor2">valor2
  <input type="checkbox" value="ambos" id="ambos">Ambos
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form id="formularioRadio">
  <input type="radio" name="identico" value="valor1">valor1
  <input type="radio" name="identico" value="valo2">valor2
  <input type="radio" name="identico" value="ambos">Ambos
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

En ambos casos evito el envio directo del formulario mediante un [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) porque en caso contrario intentaria recargar la página independientemente de lo que pongas en javascript.

En el primer caso, con **checkboxes**, lo que hago es comprobarlos todos, uno a uno, y ejecuto las acciones si se cumple su condición de `checked == true`.

En el segundo caso, con botones de **radio**, me leo el valor del botón seleccionado (recuerda que todos los botones tienen que tener el mismo `name` para que sean autoexcluyentes entre si) y los paso por un [switch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) para que ejecute tan solo la acción que coincida con el valor leído.

Ahora ya puedes decidir mejor cual de ambas opciones es la que realmente deseas usar para tus fines, que no me han quedado demasiado claros en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Los checkbox son `boolean`, así que su valor solo puede ser `true` o `false`, entonces, no le puedes asignar un valor `string`.